# How scala determines implicit type parameters for TreeSet constructor

Tags: scala

I'm doing excersises from 'Scala for the impatient' book and stumbled across this magic. I have a simple scala object for executing code:

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(charIndex("Missisipi"))
    //var s = scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int]()
  }

  def charIndex(s: String) : scala.collection.mutable.Map[Char, scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet[Int]] = {
    val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Char, scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet[Int]]()
    s.zipWithIndex.foreach{
      case (c, i) => m += c -> (m.getOrElse(c, scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet()) += i)
    }
    m
  }
}
```

No matter how it looks like (I did it the ugliest way), but in this case it doesn't compile with error:

> Error:(14, 80) diverging implicit expansion for type
>   scala.math.Ordering[T1] starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering
>         case (c, i) => m += c -> (m.getOrElse(c, scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet()) += i) Error:(14, 80) not enough
>   arguments for method apply: (implicit ord:
>   scala.math.Ordering[A])scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet[A] in class
>   SortedSetFactory. Unspecified value parameter ord.
>         case (c, i) => m += c -> (m.getOrElse(c, scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet()) += i)

But if you uncomment line in main method it will be compiled successfully. Why is this happenning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Core of a problem

If you run this example with `-Xlog-implicits` (for sbt `scalacOptions := Seq( "-Xlog-implicits" )`) you will see a lot of `[info]` messages like this

> math.this.Ordering.Tuple6 is not a valid implicit value for scala.math.Ordering[A] because:
>   [info] diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[T1]

this goes for basically every type in `math.this.Ordering` from simple like `Boolean` to `Iterables` and `Options`.

It tells us that compiler frantically trying to guess what type of `TreeSet` you are trying to construct when `getOrElse` fails. In your example it's just a `TreeSet` without any `[explicit]` typing so compiler has to find an implicit type to bind new `TreeSet` to. By specifying `Int` in `TreeSet` constructor you will eliminate search for implicits and code will work **without any magic**.

```
case ( c, i ) =>  m += c -> ( m.getOrElse( c, scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet[Int]() ) += i)
```

Now, to the main point.

### How compiler searches for implicits aka why is this magic worked

You specified that `m` is a `Map` to `TreeSet[Int]`, that's great but `.getOrElse` will return a default value for `m` when it will fail to get a first character. To construct that default value it will use definition provided by you

```
scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet()
```

In the docs for `.getOrElse` we can [see](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#getOrElse) that for default value compiler will use a result yielded from of a second parameter computation. Constructor of a `TreeSet` [need](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/TreeSet.html) to know what type of values you want to keep in that set and if it fails to see explicit definition it will look for implicits.

```
new TreeSet()(implicit ord: Ordering[A])
```

As I mentioned in the begining it will bruteforce all the possible types in `Ordering` because, you know, it has to be ordering-oriented type but the tricky part is it doesn't know what type it actually needs. Compiler has to construct a new `TreeSet` before it could `+= i` to it. It can't just look forward, see that `i` is `Int`, construct a `TreeSet[Int]` and get back to add `i` to it. That would be an actual magic.

There is a great [post](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html) on how does scala determines types for implicit parameters. Note that `SortedSet` is connected throught [traits](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/SortedSet.html) to `TreeSet` so it fails into category "some part of T". In this particular case compiler will see an explicitly defined `SortedTree[Int]` and since there is no other option will use `Int` as implicit type for `TreeSet`.